# Returned JSON is seemingly mixed up when using jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, api

I've a php script that has the following line:

```
echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true','userid'=>$userid, 'data' => $array));
```

It returns the following:

```
{
"success": "true",
"userid": "1",
"data": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Trigger",
        "image": "",
        "subtitle": "",
        "description": "",
        "range1": null,
        "range2": null,
        "range3": null
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "DWS",
        "image": "",
        "subtitle": "",
        "description": "",
        "range1": null,
        "range2": null,
        "range3": null
    }
]
```

}

But when I call a jQuery ajax as below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {name: name},
    success: function(success, userid, data) {

      if (success = true) {
         document.write(userid);
         document.write(success);
       }
   }
});
```

The `userid` is 'success'. The actual `success` one works, its `true`.

Is this malformed data being returned? Or is it simply my code?

Thanks in advance, 
Niall

Comment: Other problem - `success = true`. You probably meant `success == true` but it should just be `success`. This is why you never write `== true`, by the way.

Comment: sorry typo while i was typing in the question

Answer (score 3):

The arguments the success callback takes are defined in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
```

The response is not split up before being passed as arguments to it. You have to extract the values from the first argument.

You also need to add `header('Content-Type: application/json')` to your PHP so that jQuery will parse the response as JSON instead of as HTML when populating the first argument.

You can then test `data.success` and access `data.userid` (as well as `data.data` which will be the array assigned to the `data` property in the returned data… you might want to rename it to avoid confusion).

Note that when you test it you need to use `===` (or `==`), not the * assignment* operator you are using at present. Also note that your JSON response is returning the **string** `"true"` and not the boolean `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add your own arguments in `Success`. Change your code like this,

```
success: function(response) {

      if (response.success == true) { 
         document.write(response.userid);
         document.write(response.success);
       }
   }
```

According to jQuery Docs for `success()`,

**success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)**

A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/